# How to generate new Rx events when I click on a listbox

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a simple WPF application that contains a list of link. I would like to select few of them, add them to a an "observable list" and subscribe to it. Then the observer callback will download the link, and will proceed the next one if any of sleep.
I would also be able to update my UI to let the user know that an item has been proceeded.

Could someone give me some help doing this

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Feel free to edit your post with some code...

Comment: Simplest method, using the `Subject<T>` class. Also there are a few frameworks for using Rx with UI, consider [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Observable.FromEventPattern](http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#FromEvent) to first convert the list box of link selection events into an Observable of Uri.

Next, i would write an extension method to download link.

```
public static IObservable<bool> DownloadLink(this IObservable<Uri> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<bool>(observer =>
    {
        return source
            .Subscribe(onNext: async link =>
            {
                using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
                {
                    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(link);

                    if (isSuccess)
                        observer.OnNext(true);
                    else
                        observer.OnNext(false);
                }
            }, onError: observer.OnError, onCompleted: observer.OnCompleted);
    });
}
```

Finally, hook it up.

```
uriObservable.DownloadLink().ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe( // update ui logic here );
```

Comment: Thanks this is great. Will try to adapt it to the exact behaviour I need.